# AFNetworking block variable update issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to receive JSON back from the server, and I use this JSON to determine the return value for my Objective-C function. Regardless of what the JSON is though, the value of d doesn't change from when it is initialized (as a false value). Why is this happening? My code is as follows:

```
-(BOOL)someFunction{
    __block BOOL d;
    d = FALSE;
    //the value of d is no longer changed
    operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {
            if(![[jsonObject allKeys] containsObject:@"someString"]){
                d = TRUE;
            }
            else {
                d = FALSE;
            }
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Alert"
                                                            message: @"Could not connect to server!"
                                                           delegate: nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            d = FALSE;
        }];
    [operation start];
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an async function with a completion block that returns a success BOOL.

```
- (void)myBeautifulFunction
{
    [self someFunctionWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        if (!success) {
            [self showAlert];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)someFunctionWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion 
{
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {
            if (![[jsonObject allKeys] containsObject:@"someString"]){
                if (completion) {
                    completion(YES);
                }
            } else {
                if (completion) {
                    completion(NO);
                }
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
            if (completion) {
                completion(NO);
            }
        }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation will be performed asynchronously but you return the value of `d` synchronously. You should trigger whatever requires the value of d from the operations completion block

Comment: Do i use [operation setCompletionBlock:^(){}]?

Comment: the operation already has 2 completion blocks: 1 for success and 1 for failure, you need to handle the value of d inside those blocks